# PHP str replace

Tags: php

There is a file i trying replace that contain special char

From:

```
[v]_CØDE：BREAKER_-_01_[gg][D00B1].mkv
```

To:

```
[v]_CoDE：BREAKER_-_01_[gg][D00B1].mkv
```

But when i try the below code

```
if ($handle = opendir($refolder)) {
  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    $renameTHEfile = $entry;
    $renameTHEfile = str_ireplace("Ø","O",$renameTHEfile);
    $renameTHEfile = str_ireplace('ø','o',$renameTHEfile);
    $renameTHEfile = str_ireplace(":","_",$renameTHEfile);
    $renameTHEfile = str_ireplace("!","",$renameTHEfile);
    $renameTHEfile = str_ireplace("'","",$renameTHEfile);
    $renameTHEfile = str_ireplace('"','',$renameTHEfile);
    $renameTHEfile = str_ireplace(",","",$renameTHEfile);
    $renameTHEfile = str_ireplace("#","",$renameTHEfile);
    $renameTHEfile = str_ireplace("$","",$renameTHEfile);
    $renameTHEfile = str_ireplace('/','',$renameTHEfile);
    $renameTHEfile = str_ireplace("?","",$renameTHEfile);


    $theoldfile_rename = $refolder . $entry;

    $thenewfile_rename = $refolder . $renameTHEfile;


    $cmd_renameit = 'move "' .$theoldfile_rename. '" "'.$thenewfile_rename .'"';

    echo $cmd_renameit;

    exec($cmd_renameit);
  }
}
```

The video file will output as

```
[v]_CØDE
```

How to get it replace properly into , i also need replace the : with _

```
[v]_CODE_BREAKER_-_01_[gg][D00B1].mkv
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Consider using [`$renamed_name = strtr($original_name, array(':' => '_', '?' => '', ...))`](http://us.php.net/strtr) to perform all the replacements at once. Use the second argument of [`exec`](http://us.php.net/exec) to capture the output of the command and print it to the screen to see what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a function that renames upon your needs, you may consider something like this:

```
<?php
function rename_ani($name){
    $name = str_replace(array("Ø","ø"), "O", $name);
    $name = str_replace(":","_",$name);
    $name = str_replace(array("!","'",'"',",","#","$","/","?"),"",$name);
    return $name;
}

$anime = '[v]_CØDE:BREAKER_-_01_[gg][D00B1].mkv';
echo rename_ani($anime); // output: [v]_CODE_BREAKER_-_01_[gg][D00B1].mkv

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in the file.  Escape it like: "\ " or some other character.  In your case, just remove the space.  str_replace(" ", "", $str)